# Backbone.js setting model with data from url

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I get data back from a url: /app/api/assetDetail/{id} where the id is a parameter passed to a presenter which sets up the new assetModel and assetView.

I'm struggling with where to build and call the above url with id and then set the model.

asset presenter

```
define([
    'text!html/regions/tplAssetPage.html',
    'views/assetView',
    'collections/assets',
    'models/asset'
],
function (template, AssetView, Assets, Asset) {
    return {
        load: function (params) {                   

            $(mv.sections.mainContainer).html(template);

            var view1 = 'assetView',
                id = params || '';

            this.model = new Asset({                    
                wid: params, //sets id on model
                url: function(){
                  var url =  'api/assetDetail/' + params;
                  return url;
                  }
            }); 
            mv.i.views[view1] = new AssetView({
                'el': '#asset-container',
                model: asset
            });
            mv.i.views[view1].setup();
        },
    };
});
```

asset model

```
define([], function () {
return Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        id:''
    },

    initialize: function () {}

    });

});
```

asset view

```
define([
'text!html/tplAsset.html',
'models/asset'
], function (template, Asset) {

return Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '',

    template: _.template(template),

    initialize: function () {},

    render: function () {
        //var data = this.model.toJSON();
         this.$el.html(this.template(data));
    },

    setup: function () {
        var self = this;
        $.when(self.model.fetch())
            .done(function () {
                //console.log(self.model.toJSON());
                self.render();
            })
            .fail(function () {
                console.log('request for data has failed');
            });

              },

    events: {},
   });
});
```

now getting these errors:
     ERR: Routing error Error: A "url" property or function must be specified

```
at Backbone.View.extend.setup (/js/views/assetView.js:36:22)
   $.when(self.model.fetch())
at Object.load (/js/presenters/asset.js:34:23)
  mv.i.views[view1].setup();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the model url dynamically in your model instance:

```
 var asset = new Asset({                 
        wid: params, //sets id on model


        url: function(){
          var url = '/app/api/assetDetail/' + this.id;
          return url;
        }
  });
```

Then, after you have set the url, do `asset.fetch()`

Note that this will now be the URL for any communication with the server (`save` and `fetch`) for that model instance. If you need greater flexibiliy, you'll need to do adjust the Bacbkone `sync` method for your model.

UPDATE:

Once you've fetched the data you want for the model, you then can call the render function:

```
render: function () {
  this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON() ) );
  return this;
}
```

This will then render model data in your templates. If you're using the underscore templates it will look like:
    `<p>some html<span> <%= data %> </span><p>`

If you want to check what you have fetched, don't forget that `fetch` accepts success and error callbacks: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch

Comment: Where should I call asset.fetch()?  Within the Presenter  before or after I call setup() or within my assetView setup() function?

Comment: It depends what exactly you are doing in your `setup()` function - and if you need the fetched data from the server before you can do the setup function. If you don't, then you can put `asset.fetch()` in the assetView initialize function.

Comment: Gotcha. So does calling that url in my model instance, does that also set the model with the data returned? If not, how can I do that?

Comment: Updated my answer - fetch() sets the model with the data returned, setting the url tells the model where to look for the data it is trying to fetch.